# Spring Boot call a pod's Rest APIs in different pod's endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

In my kubernetes cluster I have two pods x and y. Both are in same kubernetes cluster. x and y pod are spring boot rest api. In x pod, the endpoint needs to call y pod's endpoint.

Could you explain how can I do this ?

Comment: You can use the k8s service in order to call the pods. Check out this - https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-kubernetes/

Answer (score 1):

So you have one application pod X that needs to call another application API deployed on pod Y. Here is what I would do in several steps:

**1. Expose your pod Y API using a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).**

Assuming your pods and services are in the same namespace, the service will be reachable from another pod at `http://service-name:port`. [More info](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns)

**2. Reference your Y pod application API in your X pod application springboot code.**

I suggest that you use an application.properties property to reference your Y application base URI in you X application. You will be able to override this property during the K8s deployment using an environment variable. Here is an example of how you would use this property in you X application.

```
@Value("${y.api.url}")
private String uri;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
System.out.println(result);
```

This property can be overridden by an environment variable. [More info on spring externalized config and property override order.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)Then you could configure this env variable in your X application deployment file.

```
env:
- name: Y_API_URL
  value: "http://service-name:port"
```

**3. To go further**

You can use a [Kustomize vars](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/vars/) to point your service name and directly use this `var` in the environement variable value you're setting during the deployment